# Delphi Rest.JSON do not work on simple class

Tags: json, rest, delphi, serialization, pascal

I am working on my main project and I have to "JSON serialize" a simple class :

```
  TServer = class
  public
    Host: string;
  end;

  TServerList = class
  public
    Servers: TArray<TServer>;
  end;

procedure Test;
begin
  var SrvLst := TServerList.Create;
  SetLength(SrvLst.Servers, 1);
  SrvLst.Servers[0] :=  TServer.Create;
  SrvLst.Servers[0].Host := 'TEST';

  var Json := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(SrvLst);
  // >> Json = '{"servers":[{"host":"TEST"}]}' , it works...
  var SrvLst2 := TJson.JsonToObject<TServerList>(Json);
  // >> SrvLst2.Server is empty ?? what's wrong ??

  // memory leaks.. nevermind
end;
```

I can't see what is wrong... Any idea ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either declare the classes this way:

```
  TServer = class
  private
    FHost: string;
  public
    property Host: string read FHost write FHost;
  end;

  TServerList = class
  private
    FServers: TArray<TServer>;
  public
    property Servers: TArray<TServer> read FServers write FServers;
  end;
```

or this way:

```
type
  TServer = class
  public
    [JSONName('Host')]
    Host: string;
  end;

  TServerList = class
  public
    [JSONName('Servers')]
    Servers: TArray<TServer>;
  end;
```

Note that the latter requires to use *REST.Json.Types*.

Comment: It works for me. Thank you Uwe.